# Why do I get complex convergence?

Tags: matlab, newton-raphson

I have problem with understanding why I get the complex convergence when using Newton-Raphson's method (own implemented) to the convergence tables down below:

```
%These equations represent the different bows that belong to the 
%two ellipses
f1 = @(x) sqrt(36 - 36/16.*(x-4).^2) + 2;
fp1 = @(x) -3.*(x-4)./(2.*sqrt(-(x-8).*x)); %Derivative to f1
f2 = @(x) -sqrt(36 - 36/16.*(x-4).^2) + 2;
fp2 = @(x) 3.*(x-4)./(2.*sqrt(-(x-8).*x)); %Derivative to f2
f3 = @(x) 0.5.*x + sqrt(10 - 0.15.*x.^2);
fp3 = @(x) 0.5 + - 0.15.*x/sqrt(10-0.15.*x^2); %Derivative to f3
f4 = @(x) 0.5.*x - sqrt(10 - 0.15.*x.^2);
fp4 = @(x) 0.5 + + 0.15.*x/sqrt(10-0.15.*x^2); %Derivative to f4

n = 10; %Number of iterations
%Table over convergence to the first intersection point between the vertical
%ellipse's upper bow and the crooked ellipse's upper bow
xStart = 4;
f = @(x) f1(x)-f3(x);
fp = @(x) fp1(x)-fp3(x);
x = xStart;
disp('iteration      x      dx')
for iter = 1:n
    dx = -f(x)/fp(x);
    x = x + dx;
    disp([iter x dx])
end

%Table over convergence to the second intersection point between the
%vertical ellipse's upper bow and the crooked ellipse's upper bow
xStart = 4;
f = @(x) f1(x) - f3(x);
fp = @(x) fp1(x) - fp3(x);
x = xStart;
disp('iteration      x      dx')
for iter = 1:n
    dx = -f(x)/fp(x);
    x = x + dx;
    disp([iter x dx])
end

%Table over convergence to the intersection point between the vertical
%ellipse's upper bow and the crooked ellipse's lower bow
xStart = 8;
f = @(x) f1(x) - f4(x);
fp = @(x) fp1(x) - fp4(x);
x = xStart;
disp('iteration      x      dx')
for iter = 1:n
    dx = -f(x)/fp(x);
    x = x + dx;
    disp([iter x dx])
end

%Table over convergence to the intersection point between the vertical
%ellipse's lower bow and the crooked ellipse's lower bow
xStart = 4;
f = @(x) f2(x) - f4(x);
fp = @(x) fp2(x) - fp4(x);
x = xStart;
disp('iteration      x      dx')
for iter = 1:n
    dx = -f(x)/fp(x);
    x = x + dx;
    disp([iter x dx])
end
```

The output I get when running these codes is as following:

```
iteration      x      dx
    1.0000   15.4861   11.4861

   2.0000 + 0.0000i   5.5336 - 0.6701i  -9.9525 - 0.6701i

   3.0000 + 0.0000i   8.4377 + 0.9203i   2.9041 + 1.5904i

   4.0000 + 0.0000i   6.8854 + 0.2759i  -1.5523 - 0.6444i

   5.0000 + 0.0000i   7.5608 - 0.1090i   0.6755 - 0.3849i

   6.0000 + 0.0000i   7.4558 - 0.0122i  -0.1050 + 0.0967i

   7.0000 + 0.0000i   7.4578 + 0.0000i   0.0019 + 0.0122i

   8.0000 + 0.0000i   7.4578 - 0.0000i   0.0001 - 0.0000i

   9.0000 + 0.0000i   7.4578 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i

  10.0000 + 0.0000i   7.4578 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i

iteration      x      dx
    1.0000   15.4861   11.4861

   2.0000 + 0.0000i   5.5336 - 0.6701i  -9.9525 - 0.6701i

   3.0000 + 0.0000i   8.4377 + 0.9203i   2.9041 + 1.5904i

   4.0000 + 0.0000i   6.8854 + 0.2759i  -1.5523 - 0.6444i

   5.0000 + 0.0000i   7.5608 - 0.1090i   0.6755 - 0.3849i

   6.0000 + 0.0000i   7.4558 - 0.0122i  -0.1050 + 0.0967i

   7.0000 + 0.0000i   7.4578 + 0.0000i   0.0019 + 0.0122i

   8.0000 + 0.0000i   7.4578 - 0.0000i   0.0001 - 0.0000i

   9.0000 + 0.0000i   7.4578 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i

  10.0000 + 0.0000i   7.4578 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i

iteration      x      dx
     1     8     0

     2     8     0

     3     8     0

     4     8     0

     5     8     0

     6     8     0

     7     8     0

     8     8     0

     9     8     0

    10     8     0

iteration      x      dx
    1.0000   -0.5192   -4.5192

   2.0000 + 0.0000i   0.6812 + 1.5032i   1.2005 + 1.5032i

   3.0000 + 0.0000i   1.7776 + 0.2145i   1.0963 - 1.2887i

   4.0000 + 0.0000i   1.2888 - 0.0404i  -0.4888 - 0.2549i

   5.0000 + 0.0000i   1.3235 - 0.0006i   0.0347 + 0.0398i

   6.0000 + 0.0000i   1.3234 + 0.0000i  -0.0001 + 0.0006i

   7.0000 + 0.0000i   1.3234 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i

   8.0000 + 0.0000i   1.3234 - 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i

   9.0000 + 0.0000i   1.3234 - 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i

  10.0000 + 0.0000i   1.3234 - 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
```

To me the result is not making any sense, since I have drawn the equations to respective ellipse in the graph and here is the picture that I got:

[image]

So again, my question is why do I get complex convergence when the solutions to the intersection points between the ellipses when (according to the graph) there should be only real solutions? Have I implemented something wrong or could it be something theoretically that I am not aware of?

Thanks for all responses in advance!

Comment: Well, if you're getting complex numbers you must be computing square roots of negative numbers at some point. I'd look at the square roots in fp1 and fp2 in particular.

Comment: As you could see in the graph, the solutions to the equations (ev. intersections between the ellipses) are real and all of the solutions are on the intervall $[0, 8]$. This is because solutions outside of the intervall will make the expression under the root term for the vertical ellipse negative and therefore produce complex numbers. But then why does not my Newton-Raphson's method converge to some points in $[0, 8]$, no matter what start number I give in my MATLAB codes?

Comment: As you can see from your output, after your first iteration you get a value of $x$ outside that interval.

Comment: I can see that, but how shall I understand the complexity with this problem? There must be real solutions (when checking on the graph above), but I only complex convergence as shown in output. It is a little difficult to understand all these things.

Comment: Why didn't you include the original equations of the ellipses in your question? That would make it easier to check.

Comment: @user21820, here are the original equations here: $0.4x^2+y^2-xy=10$ for the crooked ellipse and $((x-4)^2)/16+((y-2)^2)/36=1$ for the vertical ellipse. Sorry for not adding these details, hopefully you will be able to help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have found two phenomena that Newton's method succumbs to.

Firstly observe that the function you are using it on is complex-valued outside of a certain domain, but the tangent to the curve at many points in that domain will cut the x-axis outside. Hence you get complex values along the way.

Secondly observe that in one case you start from a point where the derivative is infinite, and hence the tangent cuts the x-axis at the same x-coordinate and the iteration is stuck there.

To avoid these you should know exactly why and when Newton's method works.
$\def\wi{\subseteq}$

Define $[m] = \{ z : |z| \le m \}$ for any complex $m$.

Given complex function $f$ such that $f(r) = 0$ and $f'(r) \ne 0$ and $f''$ exists and $\dfrac{f''}{2f'(r)} \in [m]$:

Let $a = f'(r)$.

Given $d \in [\frac{1}{5m}]$:

$f(r+d) \in ad+[\frac{1}{2}f'']d^2 \wi ad+a[m]d^2$ [by Taylor's theorem].

$f'(r+d) \in ad+[f'']d^2 \wi ad+2a[m]d^2$ [by Taylor's theorem].

$d - \dfrac{f(r+d)}{f'(r+d)} \in d - \dfrac{ad+a[m]d^2}{a+2a[m]d} = d - \dfrac{d+[m]d^2}{1+2[m]d}$

$ \wi d - (d+[m]d^2)(1+\frac{10}{3}[m]d)$ [because $\dfrac{1}{1+t} \in 1+[\frac{5}{3}]t$ for any $t \in [\frac{2}{5}]$]

$ \wi \frac{13}{3}[m]d^2+\frac{10}{3}[m]^2d^3$

$ \wi 5[m]d^2 \wi [1]d$.

Therefore Newton-Raphson converges quadratically if starting within $[\frac{1}{5m}]$ of $r$.

I leave you to check that both phenomena are due to either starting too far away or having unbounded $\dfrac{f''}{f'}$.